# How to use height: auto property in css with JQuery custom content scroller when calling mCustomScrollbar() manually

Tags: jquery, html, css, custom-scrolling, mcustomscrollbar

I am trying to use the JQuery custom scroll-bar script [discussed here](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) on my jekyll powered Github site. I would like to it use for scrolling code blocks in each page such that for each code block there is a horizontal or vertical (or both) scroll bar if there is an overflow. However, the heights of different code blocks vary and so the plugin has to work with CSS property `max-height: nPx` rather than `height: nPx`.

The problem is that if I define only `max-height: nPx` without the `height: nPx` property (which I dont want since I want height to be auto/to vary with content), then the entire code block collapses such that the scrollbars disappear altogether, along with the content.

[Here is a minimal reproducible example on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shekeine/cav7675w/) with only the `max-height` defined. Setting `height: nPx` makes the content and scrollbars work okay: except this is not an option: in my case, `height` must be auto.

I have looked at the author's example on using the plugin with `max-height` in the [provided archive](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/archive/master.zip) but in the `max-height.html` example, `mCustomScrollbar` is not called manually as I am doing in [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/shekeine/cav7675w/) so I cant just "copy-paste" from the example.

What could I be missing here?

Comment: I can say more: if you set `height:100px` scrollbars will be positioned and work incorrectly. I've tried several ways with `height:auto` and even `min-height` property - nothing works, the same for latest 3.0.5 version. Maybe better to try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar/) plugin?

Comment: Am sure Malihu worked hard on it, but this is a major limitation. Its hard for me to think of a site where all div heights are equal! Checking out your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @Gromo, no luck.. The "jQuery Scrollbar" plugin breaks even worse, am abandoning this for now until someone answers my question someday..

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar). I've updated your jsFiddle example - look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cav7675w/1/). Just included styles and scrollbar from github.io and apply it to your container when document is ready.

Do not forget to add class for scrollbar - scrollbar is fully customizable through CSS classes. List of ready-to-use classes available on [basic demo page](http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/basic.html). In your example I've used class `scrollbar-light` with background-color modification:

```
.scrollbar-light > .scroll-element {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```